# Implementing Dijkstra's algorithm in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am very new to Neo4j. Could someone kindly explain to me (step-by-step please) how I could implement the Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path between two nodes? Is it possible to simply do it using Cypher?

I already tried the shortestPath algorithm, but it is very slow:

```
MATCH (from: Location {LocationName:"x"}), (to: Location {LocationName:"y"}) , path = (from)-[:CONNECTED_TO*1..5]->(to)
RETURN path AS shortestPath, 
    reduce(distance = 0, r in relationships(path)| distance+toInt(r.Distance)) 
AS totalDistance
    ORDER BY totalDistance ASC
    LIMIT 1
```

my nodes are: Location with properties LocationID and LocationName
my relationships are: CONNECTED_TO with property Distance

I have more than 6000 relationships

please note in the code above that I have limited to 1..5
when I do not define this limit, the query does not give any results (keeps on executing)

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is possible with Cypher or with a [dedicated endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html#rest-api-execute-a-dijkstra-algorithm-and-get-a-single-path) of the Neo4j ReST API.

BTW, the examples from the Cypher Neo4j documentation are self explaining :

http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/query-match.html#_shortest_path

To get the shortestPath between two nodes :

```
MATCH (from: Location {LocationName:"x"}), (to: Location {LocationName:"y"}) , 
path = shortestPath((from)-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(to))
RETURN path
```

If you want to get all the shortest

```
MATCH (from: Location {LocationName:"x"}), (to: Location {LocationName:"y"}) , 
paths = allShortestPaths((from)-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(to))
RETURN paths
```

If you want to order by the length (number of hops) of the paths in descending order :

```
MATCH (from: Location {LocationName:"x"}), (to: Location {LocationName:"y"}) , 
paths = allShortestPaths((from)-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(to))
RETURN paths
ORDER BY length(paths) DESC
```

If you to to get the shortestPath + the sum of the relationship distance property :

```
MATCH (from: Location {LocationName:"x"}), (to: Location {LocationName:"y"}) , 
path = shortestPath((from)-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(to))
WITH REDUCE(dist = 0, rel in rels(path) | dist + rel.distance) AS distance, p
RETURN p, distance
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Christophe. The only additional point (which I forgot to mention so it is my fault), is that I would also like to have the total distance of the shortest path as a result of the query. That is why I used the reduce function in the query I posted. However, using this function tends to make the query extremely slow and practically non-usable, so could you suggest a solution to the issue. Thanks

Comment: You can have it in the return statement : RETURN path, length(shortestPath) as length

Comment: thanks for your reply. The relationships between the nodes have the property "Distance". Length of the shortest path merely returns the number of hops, and not the actual distance between node x and node y (start and end nodes). 

so is it possible to return also the distance of the shortest path in an efficient way?

Comment: I updated the answer adding an example with summing the distance property of the relationships

Comment: glad to help, if you have performance problems, check that your LocationName properties are indexed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### Another way to perform the query:

install "APOC" in neo4j
https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#utilities

```
MATCH (start:node {name:'First_node_name'}), (end:node {name: 'end_node_name'}) 
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(start, end, 'weight_property',1.0) YIELD path, weight
return path, weight
```

---

P.S.
'weight_property' this is PropertyName which must have your relationship (weight_property=225454)

returned two values:

1. path - this is the path that was found;
2. weight - summary number of weight that was colculated from each relationship